# How do you find the name of the current running funciton: current-function, this-function, current-defun, this-defun

Tags: elisp

I am trying to dynamically find the name of the current function (this-function) running i.e.

```
  (defun my-func ()
      (remove-hook 'some-hook this-function)
      (do-something))
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. However, if you describe what you are trying to do, maybe we can suggest another way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to remove the function from the hook once it is run. And I want to make the function as generic as possible.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested this, but why not write a macro to encapsulate what you want? Something like the following, maybe?

```
(defmacro one-shot-hook (name hook &rest body)
  `(defun ,name ()
     (remove-hook ',hook ',name)
     ,@body)
```

Then, for example

```
(macroexpand-all-1
 '(one-shot-hook test c-mode-hook
    (message "Yay!")))
```

gives

```
(defun test nil
  (remove-hook (quote c-mode-hook) (quote test))
  (message "Yay!"))
```

(when I've reformatted it).

This removes the problem of needing to know the name of the function you're in, which would need nasty macrology anyway (I'm not sure whether it's possible).

One more thing, I'd probably suggest just having a flag variable set to nil initially which your code tests to decide whether to run. Then you don't have to mess around adding and removing hooks all the time: the result will probably be much easier to customise and understand for anyone else using your code.